# What does the h :: t pattern matching means in OCaml?

Tags: functional-programming, ocaml

I'm reading https://ocaml.org/learn/tutorials/99problems.html and it has 2 examples:

```
# let rec last_two = function
    | [] | [_] -> None
    | [x;y] -> Some (x,y)
    | _::t -> last_two t;;
```

I understand the first one: `_::t` means pattern match anything and call it `t`

But at

```
# let rec at k = function
    | [] -> None
    | h :: t -> if k = 1 then Some h else at (k-1) t;;
```

I don't understand what `h` means. For me it should be `_:: t -> ...` to match anything and call it `t`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The pattern `_ :: t` doesn't mean what you say. It matches any non-empty list and calls the tail of the list `t`.

The pattern `h :: t` matches any non-empty list, calls the head of the list `h` (one element, the first one), and the tail of the list `t` (zero or more elements after the first one).

The operator `::` is the list constructor (often called "cons"), which is why these patterns match lists.

Here are examples of `::` as list constructor:

```
# true :: [];;
- : bool list = [true]
# 1 :: [2; 3];;
- : int list = [1; 2; 3]
```

As is usual in OCaml, the pattern for a list uses the same syntax as the constructor.

```
# match [1;2;3] with [] -> None | h :: t -> Some (h, t);;
- : (int * int list) option = Some (1, [2; 3])
```

Answer (score 1):

The `h::t` pattern matches the head and tail of the list to the variables `h` and `t`.
So if I pattern match like this:

```
match [1; 2; 3] with
| h::t -> (* Some code... *)
```

`h` will have a value of `1`, and `t` will have the value of `[2; 3]`.

`::` is a *constructor*. Pattern matching in this fashion pattern matches against constructors. They create a new datatype out of two values. `::` is a constructor, and its type, `list`, is recursive. Here's a sample definition of the `list` type:

```
type 'a list =
    | []
    | (::) 'a * ('a list)

;;
```

So the `list` type is recursive because its constructor, `::`, calls itself.

Honestly, I could write half a book on lists. They're the bread and butter of functional programming languages.

If you're wondering why you can't pattern match on *operators*, this is why. You can't pattern match on operators, only constructors.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, indeed when you type in a function let's take for example this one:

```
let is_empty (l: int list) : int =
  begin match l with
    | [] -> 1
    | h::t -> 0
  end;;
```

Therefore, in this function that tests if a list is empty or not, if `[]`, an empty list it returns one or in boolean true but if `h::t`, meaning that there is one or more value, the function returns 0, meaning it's false.

Comment: What does your answer provide that the accepted one didn't already do? And there are unused variable in yours that would trigger a compiler warning. Try not to answer to questions that are already answered unless you provide a new insight.